# Book on Weblogic Server

Tags: weblogic, weblogic11g

I am currently looking for a book that will teach me the in's and out's of using the Weblogic 10.3 as my application server.

I am currently using Servlet/JSP/EJB/JSF/JPA as the technology but right now, I am deploying it on Glassfish.

My new project involves the use of Weblogic Server and I dont have any idea how this is done.

Some of the books that I read on the net are a little dated and it covers the Weblogic 8 version.

Not sure though, but I would like to know if somebody has any instructions or preference on how to work around the Weblogic.

I basically wanted to create simple app/build/deploy on this server.

Any hints?

Thanks

Answer (score 0):

I'd suggest you to get your hands dirty and try to build/deploy your app by yourself the first time. There is no mystery in doing it for a simple app. Later on, a good starting point is [Oracle WebLogic Server 10g Release 3 (10.3) Documentation Site Map](http://docs.oracle.com/cd/E12840_01/wls/docs103/sitemap.html) (this is a popular version of WebLogic, you should look for the specific version you intend to use). There is plenty of documentation over there that will help you getting started.